# How to automatically migrate the development and test databases with `rails db:migrate` and Spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I understand that `rails db:migrate` only affects the development database.

When running `rspec` with `guard-rspec` and `spring`, the test environment doesn't automatically apply migrations. Instead, you have to have `guard` fail, manually run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate`, and run your rspec guard again. This is expected behavior according to this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25804

How could I make it so that either `rails db:migrate` does so for both environment at once, or have `spring rspec` automatically run pending migrations for the test environment as well?

I'd rather avoid a bash/zsh/shell alias because it has to be set up manually on everyone's machine.

Comment: The github issue you linked to says that the default behavior is that the migrations get run in test env automatically.

Comment: Unless you're using Spring to run rspec, then they aren't run automatically.

Comment: You don't. `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate && RAILS_ENV=development rails db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate db:test:prepare`. This is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stuart said in the comments, the only way is to either `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:migrate && RAILS_ENV=development rails db:migrate` or `rails db:migrate db:test:prepare`.